# Create a mask where the Green channel is brighter than Blue and Red?

Tags: numpy, opencv, python

I'm trying to extract the display of a green LED display from a photo, and I found that the easiest way pre-process the photo is by masking (blacken) all pixels where the green channel isn't the brightest channel. I created an algorithm to do that, but it is very slow:

```
def mask_dominant(image, color):
    # For example, if color == "green", then we blacken out
    # all pixels where green isn't the brightest pixel
    image_copy = np.copy(image)
    black_pixel = np.array([0, 0, 0], dtype=np.uint8)
    height, width, _ = image_copy.shape
    for row in range(height):
        for col in range(width):
            # OpenCV stores colors in BGR
            b, g, r = image_copy[row, col]
            zero = False
            if color == 'blue':
                if b < g or b < r:
                    zero = True
            elif color == 'green':
                if g < b or g < r:
                    zero = True
            elif color == 'red':
                if r < b or r < g:
                    zero = True
            else:
                raise AssertionError("Color must be one of blue, green, or red")
            if zero:
                image_copy[row, col] = black_pixel
    return image_copy
```

How to run it:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
image = cv2.imread("image1.jpg")
dominant = mask_dominant(image, 'green')
```

The algorithm above takes 40 seconds to run on a photo, which is way too large. Is there a built-in algorithm that does the same thing or a numpy optimization that I can use?

Comment: [Indexing with boolean arrays](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/quickstart.html#indexing-with-boolean-arrays)

Comment: @PaulPanzer - could you give an example?

Comment: There is an example at the link. And it is actually quite similar to what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Thanks @PaulPanzer - I figured it out and answered my own question

Answer (score 2):

This solution works:

```
def mask_dominant(image, color):
    # For example, if color == Green, then it blacks out
    # all pixels where green isn't the brightest pixel
    b,g,r = cv2.split(image)
    if color == 'green':
        target = g
        other1 = b
        other2 = r
    elif color == 'red':
        target = r
        other1 = g
        other2 = b
    elif color == 'blue':
        target = b
        other1 = g
        other2 = r
    else:
        raise AssertionError("invalid color: " + color)

    # Figure out which ones we need to zero & zero them
    should_zero = (target < other1) | (target < other2)
    g[should_zero] = 0
    r[should_zero] = 0
    b[should_zero] = 0

    # Merge channels back
    return cv2.merge((b,g,r))
```